# Swift: Unable to infer complex closure type with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: migration, nsfetchedresultscontroller, swift3, ios10, xcode8

After upgrading my project to Swift 3, the following initializer no longer builds:

```
1    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
2        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
3            return _fetchedResultsController!
4        }
5        
6        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
...
```

The error was on line 1:

```
"Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate"
```

Line 6 gives a further error:

```
"Generic parameter 'MyEntity' could not be inferred"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some reading, I learned that `NSFetchRequest` and `NSFetchedResultsController` are now generic in iOS 10, and Apple advises to explicitly specify their type:

```
1    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<MyEntity> {
2        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
3            return _fetchedResultsController!
4        }
5        
6        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyEntity> = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
...
```

And a useful tip (for this and other problems in the Swift 3 migration) was to simply create a new application from a template, in XCode!